# Python long filename support broken in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x

I write Python script to copy files; unfortunately it keeps failing because filename is too long(>256). Is there anyway to deal with that problem?

I'm using Python 2.5.4 and Windows XP.

Cheers,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [paths beginning with the string `\\?\`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maximum_path_length).

Comment: To piggyback on the answer, do not simply add "\\?\" to your path, add "\\\\?\\" to your path, in order to escape the needed backslashes

Answer (score 9):

In order to use the `\\?\` prefix (as already proposed), you also need to make sure you use Unicode strings as filenames, not regular (byte) strings.

Comment: Also, I found that (1) only absolute path names worked, and (2) only backslashes worked.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else looking for solution here:

1. You need to add prefix `\\?\` as already stated, and make sure string is unicode;
2. If you are using shutil, especially something like shutil.rmtree with onerror method, you'll need to modify it too to add prefix as it gets stripped somewhere on the way.

You'll have to write something like:

```
def remove_dir(directory):
    long_directory = '\\\\?\\' + directory
    shutil.rmtree(long_directory, onerror=remove_readonly)

def remove_readonly(func, path, excinfo):
    long_path = path
    if os.sep == '\\' and '\\\\?\\' not in long_path:
        long_path = '\\\\?\\' + long_path
    os.chmod(long_path, stat.S_IWRITE)
    func(long_path)
```

This is an example for Python 3.x so all strings are unicode.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer by uDev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926716/8028981) suggests to add

```
# Fix long path access:
import ntpath
ntpath.realpath = ntpath.abspath
```

It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that works for me is to change directory into the place to which I want to copy:

```
import os
import shutil

def copyfile_long_path(src, dst):
    
    src_abs = os.path.abspath(src)
    dst_abs = os.path.abspath(dst)
    
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(dst))
    shutil.copyfile(src_abs, os.path.filename(dst))
    os.chdir(cwd)
    
    if not os.path.isfile(dst_abs):    
        raise Exception("copying file failed")
```