# How to append '\\?\' to the front of a file path in Python

Tags: python, filepath, backslash

I'm trying to work with some long file paths (Windows) in Python and have come across some problems.  After reading the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365797/python-long-filename-support-broken-in-windows), it looks as though I need to append '\\?\' to the front of my long file paths in order to use them with os.stat(filepath).  The problem I'm having is that I can't create a string in Python that ends in a backslash.  The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash) points out that you can't even end strings in Python with a single '\' character.

Is there anything in any of the Python standard libraries or anywhere else that lets you simply append '\\?\' to the front of a file path you already have?  Or is there any other work around for working with long file paths in Windows with Python?  It seems like such a simple thing to do, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: "append to the front" is a confusing phrase.  You might mean "prepend".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"\\\\?\\" should give you exactly the string you want.

Longer answer: of course you can end a string in Python with a backslash.  You just can't do so when it's a "raw" string (one prefixed with an 'r').  Which you usually use for strings that contains (lots of) backslashes (to avoid the infamous "leaning toothpick" syndrome ;-))

Comment: Raw string literals are to escape escape-sequences (`\"`, `\n`, `\(`, `\s`, etc.), which is why you can't end one in a backslash.

Comment: Yep, this works.  I'd tried this before and gotten an error, although that turned out to be because I had been doing it with a file path like "\\?\D:somefile" instead of "\\?\D:\somefile".

Answer (score 0):

Even with a raw string, you can end in a backslash with:

```
>>> print r'\\?\D:\Blah' + '\\'
\\?\D:\Blah\
```

or even:

```
>>> print r'\\?\D:\Blah' '\\'
\\?\D:\Blah\
```

since Python concatenates to literal strings into one.